# summation in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have this query from database SQL SERVER 2000:

```
SELECT D.KODDESIGNASI AS KJB_KODKAT,  
(SELECT ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AJW_HAK) FROM AGIHANJPAT WHERE AJW_KODALAT=K.KODALAT),0))     
AS PERJAWATAN
FROM KAT_PERALATAN AS K, KOD_PERALATAN AS A, DESIGNASI AS D 
WHERE K.KODKATEGORI=A.KODKATEGORI AND A.KODDESIGNASI=D.KODDESIGNASI AND   
D.KODDESIGNASI='BST'
ORDER BY D.PERIHAL
```

From this query, I got this result

```
KJB_KODKAT    PERJAWATAN
------------------------
BST           2
BST           6
BST           1265
BST           54
...           ...
...           ...
...           ...
```

Now, I want to get total value of `PERJAWATAN WHERE D.KODDESIGNASI='BST'`.
I try to modify my query like this:

```
SELECT D.KODDESIGNASI AS KJB_KODKAT,  
SUM(SELECT ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AJW_HAK) FROM AGIHANJPAT WHERE 
        AJW_KODALAT=K.KODALAT),0)))     
AS PERJAWATAN
FROM KAT_PERALATAN AS K, KOD_PERALATAN AS A, DESIGNASI AS D 
WHERE K.KODKATEGORI=A.KODKATEGORI AND A.KODDESIGNASI=D.KODDESIGNASI AND   
D.KODDESIGNASI='BST'
ORDER BY D.PERIHAL
```

However, I got error. Can anyone help me fix my error? I'm very new with `SQL SERVER 2000`. Is it different from `MYSQL`?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I got this error: `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Answer (score 0):

```
    select KJB_KODKAT, SUM(PERJAWATAN)    
    from (
    SELECT D.KODDESIGNASI AS KJB_KODKAT,  
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AJW_HAK) FROM AGIHANJPAT WHERE AJW_KODALAT=K.KODALAT),0))     
    AS PERJAWATAN
    FROM KAT_PERALATAN AS K, KOD_PERALATAN AS A, DESIGNASI AS D 
    WHERE K.KODKATEGORI=A.KODKATEGORI AND A.KODDESIGNASI=D.KODDESIGNASI AND   
    D.KODDESIGNASI='BST'
    ORDER BY D.PERIHAL) Z
group by KJB_KODKAT
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT KJB_KODKAT, SUM(PERJAWATAN)
FROM
(
SELECT  D.KODDESIGNASI AS KJB_KODKAT,  
        (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AJW_HAK) FROM AGIHANJPAT WHERE AJW_KODALAT=K.KODALAT),0))AS PERJAWATAN
FROM    KAT_PERALATAN AS K, KOD_PERALATAN AS A, DESIGNASI AS D 
WHERE   K.KODKATEGORI=A.KODKATEGORI 
        AND A.KODDESIGNASI=D.KODDESIGNASI 
        AND D.KODDESIGNASI='BST'
)SourceQuery
```

This should work, however, you should use joins instead of your original code.